# Carousel with image map linked to next image

Tags: javascript, html

The long and short of it is I'm trying to use a carousel, and instead of using next and previous buttons to navigate to other images, I want to use image mapping to link to other images. I'm quite stuck, so I appreciate any advice!

My carousel is from this site's tutorial (https://christianheilmann.com/2015/04/08/keeping-it-simple-coding-a-carousel/
). Here's my html code:

```
        <ol class="content"> 
        <li>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" alt="mag" usemap="#map" class="img-responsive">
            <map name="map">
                <area shape=poly coords="500,80,1080,80,1080,550,500,550" href="img2" title="vent1" > <!--where should href link to?? -->
            </map>
        </li>
        <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/199/200" alt="2"></li>
        <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/199" alt="3"></li> 
    </ol>
```

My javascript:

```
carousel = (function(){

// Read necessary elements from the DOM once
var box = document.querySelector('.simbox');
var next = box.querySelector('.next');
var prev = box.querySelector('.prev');

// Define the global counter, the items and the 
// current item 
var counter = 0;
var items = box.querySelectorAll('.content li');
var amount = items.length;
var current = items[0];

box.classList.add('active');

// navigate through the carousel

function navigate(direction) {
    // hide the old current list item 
    current.classList.remove('current');

    // calculate the new position
    counter = (counter + direction) % amount;
    counter = counter < 0 ? amount - 1 : counter;

    // set new current element 
    // and add CSS class
    current = items[counter];
    current.classList.add('current');
}

// add event handlers to buttons
next.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    navigate(1);
});
prev.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    navigate(-1);
});

// show the first element 
// (when direction is 0 counter doesn't change)
navigate(0);})();
```

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use image mapping to link to another image, as in what to put after href="". Elron, down below, recommended linking to a function

Answer (score 0):

You asked *"where should href link to?"*

you can link it to `href="javascript:navigate(1)"` that way, when you click on the area, it will fire the `navigate(1)` function that will cause the carousel go to the next item.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks so much!!